# Register generic type with parameters via IServiceCollection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a parameter which I want to broadcast during type registration:

```
CacheModeTypes cacheModeType;
```

I have a code which works well with Autofac:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CacheProvider<,>)).As(typeof(ICacheProvider<,>))
         .WithParameter((p, ctx) => true, (p, ctx) => if(someCriteria) return  CacheModeTypes.Default; else return CacheModeTypes.NoCache;)
         .SingleInstance();
```

But I cant do the same with `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection`. I can`t send parameter for my generic type during registration:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ICacheProvider<,>), typeof(CacheProvider<,>));
```

`CacheProvider` looks like this one:

```
public class CacheProvider<TKey, TData> : ICacheProvider<TKey, TData> where TData : class
{
    private readonly CacheModeTypes _cacheModeType;
    public CacheProvider(CacheModeTypes cacheModeType)
    {
        _cacheModeType = cacheModeType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the `CacheModeTypes` as well

```
services.AddTransient<CacheModeTypes>(sp => {
     if(someCriteria) 
        return CacheModeTypes.Default; 
    else 
        return CacheModeTypes.NoCache;        
});
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ICacheProvider<,>), typeof(CacheProvider<,>));
```

So the container is aware of it when resolving the `CacheProvider` implementations

Comment: @MaksymVoronytskyi show the error message so we can figure out the cause